# Force stop after clicking on the delete button

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have been struggling with this for the past few days/weeks.

1. Press the 'C' or 'Delete button'.
2. Press any operator button
3. [Here is a video producing the problem (hosted on vid.me ~34 MB)](https://vid.me/I7Oi)
4. [Link to repo containing the code I am debugging.(github)](https://github.com/jibolash/crunch/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/andela/currencycalc)

The error

Tl;dr

- at com.andela.currencycalc.math.MathOperations.equals(MathOperations.java:53)
- at com.andela.currencycalc.buttons.ButtonHandler.equalsButtonClicked(ButtonHandler.java:61)
- at com.andela.currencycalc.MainActivity.equalsButtonClickHandler(MainActivity.java:36)

**Entire error**

```
04-04 17:55:50.906 8497-8497/com.andela.currencycalc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:com.andela.currencycalc, PID: 8497java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
at com.andela.currencycalc.math.MathOperations.equals(MathOperations.java:53)
at com.andela.currencycalc.buttons.ButtonHandler.equalsButtonClicked(ButtonHandler.java:61)
at com.andela.currencycalc.MainActivity.equalsButtonClickHandler(MainActivity.java:36)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

Comment: how are you calling onclick method?

Comment: according to your log i think your problem is that in lines that you are parsing your data (like this line : `Float.parseFloat(displayHandler.getDisplay().getText().toString()), operatorCharacter)` in your `MathOperations.java` file) you should chek to see if your text is empty or not. so if it is not empty then you can parse it otherwise you would face with error.

Comment: and also you should check and see if your text data is parse able in float format or not (for example use `try{} catch(){}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code i can say you are doing wrong here so replace your code in equals method of MathOperations class

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(displayHandler.getDisplay().getText().toString())) {

    displayHandler.addToSecondDisplay(buttonHandler.getOperandSpinner().getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    Float.parseFloat(displayHandler.getDisplay().getText().toString()), "");

    calculate();

}
```

This will check for null and empty text before parsing.

Comment: You sir made my day. I just applied, "if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(displayHandler.getDisplay().getText().toString())) {" to the operator button also.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
>   ...
>   at com.andela.currencycalc.math.MathOperations.equals(**MathOperations.java:53**)
>   ...

You are calling Float.parseFloat(string) there with the empty string as argument.

You should heck the input before this method or catch that exception and handle that situation in a meaningful way.
Or you could try to find some other way to guarantee the input is a valid float.